# Why does my render smudge?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects, compositing-nodes

[image]

Hey everyone, new to blender. Learning the best I can. 
Just practising some sun light with cycles render. My renders are coming out smudgy, all detail lost. 
All of the render settings are normal, render sampling is at 500. No ambient occlusion or HDRI image. 
Am using denoise in the compositing, have tried to research this answer. I boosted my sampling and still smudgy. My textures have a diffuse, roughness and normal map.
If more info is required then I will do my best to give that info.

Thank you for reading this ^^

Comment: Usually smudge is due to the denoiser. Bringing your samples closer to 1000 might be necessary for a fully detailed image. Your image doesn't seem to be suffering from denoising, though. However, if you want better details, you may consider boosting the number of image pixels as well (Output Properties, Resolution X, Resolution Y). Another thing you can check is camera focus. There's nothing prominently wrong with your image, so it's difficult to understand what's wrong. What area is the smudge in?

Comment: Hey :). As @Denis pointed out, these smudges are definitely Denoiser artifacts. What kind of denoiser are you using?

Comment: In the compositor panel there is a denoise node, which can be plug in between the render layers and composite.   https://i.imgur.com/aeULAfh.jpg

Comment: @AndrewHam Hey :). In that case, your best bet is to increase the sample count. Indoor scenes often require 1000+ samples even with denoiser, 2000+ isn't unusual.

Comment: Okay, thank you ever so much for your help. It has worked with more samples. Feel like a dumb ass :D the answers were much grateful, so thanks.

Comment: @AndrewHam No problem, we've all been there :). Good luck with your project.